# creating a new instance of a scala trait

Tags: scala, traits

Please explain this in Scala.

If I have a

```
 trait A
```

I cannot do a

```
val a = new A
```

But this example trait,

```
 trait DS[-In, +Out]{def apply(i: In): Out}
```

can have an instance of

```
val t1 = new DS[Any, Int]{def apply(i: Any) = i.toString.toInt}
```

How is this allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works just fine with a class body `{}`.

```
val a = new A {}
```

Comment: So we can create an instance of a trait?

Comment: @Srinivas yes, provided that all members have a concrete implementation. If the trait already provides all the concrete implementations, then you just need to add an empty body `{ }`

Comment: Syntactically, that's what it looks like, but technically, you are creating an *anonymous* class that implements the trait. I.e., you are defining the class in-line, as per @puhlen's answer.

Answer (score 8):

What is happening is that by providing a class body you are creating an anonymous class inline that extends the trait.