# Instantiation of a single trait vs a mixin

Tags: scala

Any idea why I cannot create an instance of a single trait, without providing a class body:

```
trait MyTrait
val test1 = new MyTrait // Does not compile.
val test2 = new MyTrait {} // Compiles.
```

But if I add another one into the mix then I will be able to create an instance:

```
trait MyTrait
trait SecondTrait
val anotherTest = new SecondTrait with MyTrait  // Compiles successfully.
```

I would have expected the same behavior.

**Side note:** I already had read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241863/creating-a-new-instance-of-a-scala-trait). But the presence of the trait body does not answer my problem, as the second example still does not have a body. Thus, why does the compiler consider the second example as an anonymous class?

Comment: I'm guessing that, if you give `MyTrait` an actual code body, then you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: Edit your question to include the complete trait.

Comment: Note that [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_traits.htm) doesn't show any examples of instantiating a trait all by itself.  Kinda makes sense, really, since the tutorial describes a trait as essentially a Java interface with behavior.  So to use it, you have to *inherit it*, just as you did with your second example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the code is ok as it is, your tutorial does not claim to cover all scala features

Comment: If it were OK, it would work.

Comment: the second one works ... that's the question, how come the second one works (given that you still keep the first trait definition )

Comment: Have you tried using `extends` with your trait, as the tutorial describes?  Inheriting and creating an instance are not at all the same thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not trying to find a workaround, I'm just asking why it's possible to have an instance in the second case while in the first case it's not possible.

Comment: I use a car to get my groceries home from the store.  Today I tried a skateboard, but it didn't work.  Why can't I use my skateboard instead of a car if they both have wheels?

Comment: Include the exact wording of the compiler error message in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you're wrong. Let me correct your statement so that it fits my question: I use a Vehicle which requires Gas to go to work , why can't I use a Vehicle

Comment: Include the exact wording of the compiler error message in your question.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45241896/6176274

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov: Which says "provide a body," which is exactly what I said in my very first comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yep. Basically, this boils down into how the Scala traits encoded in Scala. They are under the hood the java interfaces.

Comment: guys, I understand that first example will work If I provide a body but I don't provide a body neither in the second case and it still works

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I still don't see how is this a duplicate, my second case still holds, there's no body for the second trait and the instance can be created succesfully

Comment: Your second case works *because it has a body* (the first trait).

Comment: You're probably right, maybe you know how that is expanded into a body in which case you should post it as an answer

Comment: It doesn't have to "expand into a body," it just has to have a body (to satisfy the compiler).  Doesn't mean that it will work when you try to run it, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ok so where's the body in the second case ?  ... that's why I'm saying that probably the compiler creates a body ...

Comment: The body in the second case is `{ self : MyTrait => }`

Comment: Wait ... the first case still not works if I add a body like trait MyTrait { }, even if I say trait MyTrait { self => } ... Is this a body ?  ... if yes, then your answer does not hold

Comment: @RobertHarvey that does not really answer the question. The second example does not compile because `SecondTraint` has a body. It does compile because the `with OtherTrait` is enough for the compiler to consider it as a new anonymous non-abstract class, for which it then creates a new instance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, would you mind removing the "duplicate" ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, isn't that an inconsistency in the compiler?

Comment: @humbletrader Not sure, I tried to search for the specs of anonymous classes for Scala, but did not find anything. That is why I had not answered the question. Hope somebody with more understanding of the compiler / language specs will be able to provide a concise answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey IMHO, you should remove the duplication as well as all your comments. You really did not understand the question _(I agree it was not really clear at first)_. But, neither the duplicate nor your comments solve the question and are not useful at all.

Comment: Wow, a lot of comments here... anyways, check out https://users.scala-lang.org/t/instantiation-of-traits/3505/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for [Instance Creation Expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions) says:

> A simple instance creation expression is of the form `new c` where `c` is a constructor invocation. Let `T` be the type of `c`. Then `T` must denote a (a type instance of) a non-abstract subclass of `scala.AnyRef`...
>
> A general instance creation expression is of the form `new t` for some class template `t`. Such an expression is equivalent to the block `{ class a extends t; new a }` where `a`
> is a fresh name of an anonymous class which is inaccessible to user programs.

In `new MyTrait`, `MyTrait` is *syntactically* a legal constructor invocation. So `new MyTrait` is a *simple* instance creation expression which fails to compile because `MyTrait` doesn't "denote a non-abstract subclass of `scala.AnyRef`".

But `SecondTrait with MyTrait` can't be a constructor invocation, so it's treated as a class template for a *general* instance creation expression, which creates an anonymous class. The same applies to `MyTrait {}`.